# Excel function Fill Up Cells

Tags: function, vba, excel

Consider the following data on excel:

```
1|0.2
2|0.2
3|3.4
4|
5|1.5
6|1.8
7|
8|4.2
```

Write a VBA function that scans through the selection, finds the empty spots and then t
fills them with a numerical value which is passed through the signature of the function.
Output:
Numbers

```
1|0.2
2|0.2
3|3.4
4|0
5|1.5
6|1.8
7|0.0
8|4.2
```

Hi everyone, i have a question above.

I was wondering if anyone can look at my code and tell me whats wrong with my code.

```
Public Function MyFill(thisRange As Range)
Dim x As Range
Set x = thisRange
ReDim Y(x.Length)
Dim i As Integer
For Each x In thisRange
    If (x.Value = Empty) Then
        Y(i) = 0
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Y(i) = x.Value
Next x
MyFill = Y
End Function
```

Comment: Where is Y defined and what type is it defined as?

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function MyFill(thisRange As Range)
Dim X As Range
Set X = thisRange
MyFill = X
End Function
```

Apparently the answer i was looking for is much simpler than I thought.

Comment: That doesn't change the range in any way. In fact this function does nothing at all